# Create WordPress instance inside another instance?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I'm trying to install an WordPress v4.1.1 instance inside an existing instance of WordPress v4.1.1.

example:

```
http://website.com
```

is a website build in WordPress, and I want to create another website inside a subfolder of the current WordPress website

```
http://website.com/business
```

This way I would have two different websites with one inside another. The problem is that when reaching `http://website.com/business` it returns an `404 error` from the outer website.

I think the problem is the `.htaccess` file that redirects to the outer instance of WordPress.

How do I fix the `.htaccess` files? which are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: try remove this line and see if it solves this problem- RewriteBase /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create another website inside a subfolder of the current WordPress website, there is a WordPress feature that was created and does exactly the same thing: take a closer look here https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /business/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not solve the problem. (mod_rewrite is enabled)